Handling cycles in topological sorting in T-SQL
I've been trying to write a T-SQL script - I am aware it's probably not the best tool for this scenario - that can do a topological sort given a table of nodes and their edges.
I've eventually come up with the following script inspired by Khan's algorithm:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Edges

CREATE TABLE #Edges (EdgeId INT IDENTITY(1,1), FromNode INT, ToNode INT);

INSERT INTO #Edges (FromNode, ToNode) VALUES
(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 5), (5, 6), (7, NULL), (8, NULL)--, (6, 4);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AllNodesMaster CREATE TABLE #AllNodesMaster (node INT);
INSERT INTO #AllNodesMaster SELECT DISTINCT FromNode AS node FROM #Edges UNION SELECT DISTINCT ToNode AS Node FROM #Edges

DECLARE @CurrentLevel INT = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AllNodes      CREATE TABLE #AllNodes      (node INT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #OrderedNodes  CREATE TABLE #OrderedNodes  (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), node INT, level INT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #InDegrees     CREATE TABLE #InDegrees     (node INT, InDegreeCount INT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Queue         CREATE TABLE #Queue         (node INT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DeletedEdges  CREATE TABLE #DeletedEdges  (node INT);

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT FromNode FROM #Edges)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #AllNodes SELECT DISTINCT FromNode AS node FROM #Edges UNION SELECT DISTINCT ToNode AS Node FROM #Edges

    INSERT INTO #InDegrees
    SELECT T.node, ISNULL (C.InDegreeCount,  0) AS inDegreeCount
    FROM #AllNodes T
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ToNode AS node, COUNT(FromNode) AS InDegreeCount FROM #Edges GROUP BY ToNode) C ON T.node = C.node
    WHERE T.node IS NOT NULL

    INSERT INTO #Queue SELECT node FROM #InDegrees WHERE inDegreeCount = 0

    INSERT INTO #OrderedNodes (node, level) SELECT node, @CurrentLevel FROM #Queue

    DELETE FROM #Edges OUTPUT deleted.FromNode INTO #DeletedEdges WHERE EdgeId IN (SELECT EdgeId FROM #Edges WHERE FromNode IN (SELECT node FROM #Queue))

    TRUNCATE TABLE #Queue

    INSERT INTO #Queue SELECT node FROM #AllNodes WHERE node NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT FromNode AS node FROM #Edges UNION SELECT DISTINCT ToNode AS Node FROM #Edges) AND node NOT IN (SELECT node FROM #DeletedEdges)

    TRUNCATE TABLE #AllNodes
    TRUNCATE TABLE #DeletedEdges
    TRUNCATE TABLE #InDegrees

    SET @CurrentLevel = @CurrentLevel + 1;

END

SELECT
node, level
FROM
(
SELECT
nm.node,
CASE
    WHEN orn.node IS NOT NULL THEN orn.level
    ELSE @CurrentLevel
END AS level
FROM
#AllNodesMaster nm
LEFT JOIN #OrderedNodes orn ON nm.node = orn.node
) T
WHERE
node IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
level
ASC

I chose to go for an iterative approach using a WHILE loop instead of a recursive CTE, as I found the latter harder to debug and often hanged endlessly.
The question is, how could cycles be best handled in this scenario using this implementation? Currently, if a cycle is introduced (the commented line "--, (6, 4)" does this), then the WHILE gets caught in an endless loop.
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Usually one keeps track of previously visited nodes and then ignore if those nodes come back. I'd rather not parse your sql, but there should be a way of doing that somehow in your code

This is one old-fashioned solution for handling cycles in parent/child hierarchies by tracking visited nodes. It could be modified to walk edges in a graph or digraph and track nodes, edges or both. A related answer is here and another variation here.

Aside: A couple of tips for debugging CTEs. If you break down the solution into several CTEs within a single WITH you can SELECT the results of any of the intermediate CTEs to display for debugging. (Example.) If the problem is in a recursive CTE you can add a depth counter to display the levels of recursion and use the MaxRecursion query hint to limit how far the recursion runs.

The solution to this that worked for me is to do the cycle detection before doing the topological search.
The implementation for cycle detection in a directed graph was taken from here. Which also came from this answer.
